# SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

Tags: python, django, arguments, django-queryset, repeat

I have the below queryset:

```
site_list = SiverifyVerificationSite.objects.filter(pattern_id=int(p_id), if_target=bundle.obj.pattern.if_target).exclude(ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-mt23run1-')
```

It works if I give one exclude filter whereas If I include the second filter in exclude it throws (SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated). Ideally what I want is:

```
site_list = SiverifyVerificationSite.objects.filter(pattern_id=int(p_id), if_target=bundle.obj.pattern.if_target).exclude(ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-mt23run1-', ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-20251-')
```

Is there any operators to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may just chain the excludes:

```
qs = qs.exclude(ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-mt23run1-')
qs = qs.exclude(ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-20251-')
```

It does not cause any extra queries this way - Django won't evaluate the queryset until necessary.

An alternative is to build up the filter with `Q` objects.

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = Q(ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-mt23run1-') | Q(ptrf__istartswith='ptrf-20251-')
qs = qs.exclude(q)
```

Comment: Chain will work. I was wondering if there might be any operators to do this.

Comment: There is.  Added an alternative option which uses `|` operator on `Q` objects.  I think chaining is more readable, though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: post__contains

When writing **the [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) code** with **2 `post__contains` arguments** in **`test()` view** to run **`AND` operator** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    # Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(
             post__contains="popular", post__contains="simple"
         )      # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑        # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑
    print(qs)

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, I used **`&`** or [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and **`&`** to run **`AND` operator** with **`filter()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "&"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") & \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "&" 
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") & 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, the error above was solved:

```
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "&"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "Q()" and "&"
[22/Dec/2022 12:08:22] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```